# Chrome/Safari category page rendering

Tags: category, chrome-browser

I'm having a tedious issue on the category page of my e-commerce:
only using Chrome or Safari the web page **SOMETIMES** breaks (img 1) [image]

instead of img 2 [image]

If I try to read the code on Chrome browser by Delepoper Tool I see this DOM piece:

```
    <ul>
<li class="item span33 first jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-1 jcarousel-item-1-horizontal" style="height: 490px; float: left; list-style: none;" jcarouselindex="1">
                                <div class="catalog-image">
                                </div>
</li>
<li class="item span33 jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-2 jcarousel-item-2-horizontal" style="height: 490px; float: left; list-style: none;" jcarouselindex="2">
                                <div class="catalog-image">
                                </div>
</li>
<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-3 jcarousel-item-3-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal" jcarouselindex="3" style="float: left; list-style: none; height: 490px;"></li>
                                <div class="catalog-image">
                                </div>
</ul>
```

If I try to read the source code, all seems at the right place (the third `<li>` has the right style classes and the `<div>` is correctly in `<li>` tag).

Why this behavior and what can be a solution?

Thanks in advance,
WaPoNe

Comment: make sure the LI is postilion:relative -- another suggestion use OWL carousel as it is responsive and touch support. If this didn't fix please update with link so I can review it for you

Comment: A page URL can be: http://shop.classicdesignitalia.com/fr/breuer-designer but it happens in a random order.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing you link, you have an extra  in the code. Please review your code and make sure the closing tags are in the right place. in source code line 1090

Sorry it is here

```
<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-3 jcarousel-item-3-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal" jcarouselindex="3" style="float: left; list-style: none; height: 490px;"></li>
                                <div class="catalog-image">
                                </div>
```

Should be

```
<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-3 jcarousel-item-3-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal" jcarouselindex="3" style="float: left; list-style: none; height: 490px;">
                                <div class="catalog-image">
                                </div> </li>
```

Comment: The issue is just that.. in the source the code is something like that:

<li class="item span33">
<div class="catalog-image"></div>
</li>

and it seem correct but SOMETIMES something goes wrong!

Comment: I don't understand can you please explain more? any way I can see the source code of list.phtml

Comment: How can I send you the code of list.phtml?

Comment: zip it and load it to an ftp after you can share the link

Comment: Can I send you by email? It is a simple file..